# Excel VBA On Error GoTo not working as intended

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling, goto

I'm using On Error GoTo to catch an error with my function *Linterp,* which takes in a cell and two ranges. Sometimes, Linterp throws an error, in which case I just want to set the cell equal to 5. Other times, however, when Linterp does not throw an error and correctly returns an expected number, e.g. 3.25 or something of the sort, the function still goes to "Case 1" and sets the cell back to 5.

Furthermore, despite [this suggestion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/on-error-statement#:%7E:text=The%20On%20Error%20GoTo%200,after%20the%20error%20is%20handled.) that I insert an Exit Sub after On Error Goto, I don't think I can do that in my particular case because I want the function to keep iterating through each cell even if one of the cells executes the Linterp correctly on the first attempt.

```
Sub Linterp_Test_1()
    For Each cell In Selection
        Set cell_index = Cells(3, "I")
        Set cell_xs = Range(Cells(cell.Row, "K"), Cells(cell.Row, "O"))
        Set cell_ys = Range(Cells(cell.Row, "D"), Cells(cell.Row, "H"))
        
        On Error GoTo Case1
        cell.Value = Linterp(cell_index, cell_xs, cell_ys)
        Resume Next
        
Case1:
        cell.Value = 5
        Resume Next
        
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to clear the error when the error happens. You may want to see [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19477375/when-is-it-appropriate-to-explicitly-use-err-clear) Also you do not need to use `GoTo Case1`. Check how `On Error Resume Next` is used with `If Err.Number <> 0 Then` in that post...

Comment: It would be nice if you could post code of the `Linterp` function since using ranges is not quite efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Error Handling

I prefer the first solution in your case.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Linterp_Test_1()
    
    If TypeName(Selection) <> "Range" Then Exit Sub
    
    On Error Resume Next
    
    For Each cell In Selection
        
        Set cell_index = Cells(3, "I")
        Set cell_xs = Range(Cells(cell.Row, "K"), Cells(cell.Row, "O"))
        Set cell_ys = Range(Cells(cell.Row, "D"), Cells(cell.Row, "H"))
        
        cell.Value = Linterp(cell_index, cell_xs, cell_ys)
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            cell.Value = 5
            Err.Clear
        End If
    
    Next cell
    
    On Error GoTo 0
    
End Sub


Sub Linterp_Test_2()
    
    If TypeName(Selection) <> "Range" Then Exit Sub

    For Each cell In Selection
        
        Set cell_index = Cells(3, "I")
        Set cell_xs = Range(Cells(cell.Row, "K"), Cells(cell.Row, "O"))
        Set cell_ys = Range(Cells(cell.Row, "D"), Cells(cell.Row, "H"))
        
        On Error Resume Next
        cell.Value = Linterp(cell_index, cell_xs, cell_ys)
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then cell.Value = 5
        On Error GoTo 0
    
    Next cell
    
End Sub
```

Comment: I prefer the 2nd. The first one will supress other errors as well which is not recommended....

Comment: @SiddharthRout: Thx. What about efficiency? Is there actually a difference? If not, then you're absolutely right.

Comment: In such a case, I am willing to sacrifice efficiency as compared to ignoring other errors :)  Honestly if efficiency becomes a big issue then I will use array to perform the action and then write back to the worksheet in 1 go :)

Comment: Thank you @VBasic2008 – option 1 worked just fine. 

Comment: I'm glad you liked it, but be careful, SiddharthRout knows what he's talking about. I've presented both solutions because I only recently got to fully understand error handling. The missing parts were: 1. Why do I need `Err.Clear` when `On Error Goto 0` handles it safely? To keep `On Error Resume Next` all the time 'active'. (`On Error Goto 0` 'shuts if off'. 2. (not related to your case) The mystery about `Resume` and `Resume Next`, where `Resume` continues with the same line where the error occurred e.g. if you plan to change some values until there is no error anymore.

Comment: @Anders.  Option 1 will work "just fine",... until it doesn't.   By that I mean, if the only error that occurs is the one you expect,  then yes it works.   One day another error will occur and that code will swallow it and not tell you anything, and you'll get incorrect results.  Seriously,  use option 2.